# Bind Alt + Tab shortcut to a mouse button on xfce

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse

Anyone knows how to bind Alt + Tab shortcut to a mouse button on xfce?

Answer (score 3):

**xvkbd and xbindkeys**

Let's say we want to bind some mouse buttons to keyboard ones. The problem we will encounter is that we do not know how to emulate a key press. Here comes in handy `xvkbd`. We can use it along with `xbindkeys`.

```
xbindkeys --defaults >> ~/.xbindkeysrc
xbindkeys
```

To restart xbindkeys type:

```
pkill -f xbindkeys
xbindkeys
```

Here's example ~/.xbindkeysrc config:

```
"xvkbd  -text "\[F8]""
       m:0x0 + b:8
"xvkbd  -text "\[Shift]\[Left]""
       m:0x0 + b:9
"xvkbd  -text "\[Shift]\[Right]""
       m:0x0 + b:10
"xvkbd  -text 2"
       m:0x0 + b:11
"xvkbd  -text 3"
       m:0x0 + b:12
```

If you want to check your mouse buttons number use `xev`. Don't forget to type capital letters in `xvkbd` -text usage and to escape opening bracket with `\` or you get simply `[Shift]` written.

Here is an example for `xbindkeys` to enable x selection paste(third click pasting), you need both `xsel` and `xvkbd` installed, What it does it executes that command whenever button 13 of the mouse is pressed (in `~/.xbindkeysrc`) :

```
"xvkbd -no-jump-pointer -text "\D1$(xsel)" 2>/dev/null"
b:13
```

And yes, you can bind typing obscene words to mouse keys. Excerpt taken from [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/All_Mouse_Buttons_Working)